# Вывод категорий в шаблоне category.php

Tags: wordpress

Добрый вечер. Столкнулся с таким вопросом:
У меня на сайте есть две категории с записями (id-1 и id-2). Список записей я вывожу через шаблон category.php.
Однако когда перехожу по ссылкам http://site/category/id-1 и http://site/category/id-2, то на странице отображаются абсолютно все записи с первой и второй категории. Как использовать один шаблон для вывода нескольких рубрик, чтобы туда попадали только записи с нужной рубрики?
Не хочется один код разбрасывать по разным шаблонам - category-1.php и category-2.php

Comment: А какой код в category.php? Стандартный цикл WordPress должен работать как Вы описали.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Только что разобрался. Это из-за того, что нарушил цикл параметром query_posts('posts_per_page=-1'). После удаления строки все заработало.

Comment: параметры цикла лучше переопределять с помощью хука [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) .

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только что разобрался. Это из-за того, что нарушил цикл параметром query_posts('posts_per_page=-1'). После удаления строки все заработало.